# Actionscript 3-- Trying to fix a delay that is occuring upon key press.

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to setup keyboard control for my game and ran into an interesting obstacle: When the player presses a key to move in a specific direction a delay in the physical movement occurs similar to the delay that happens when editing text.

For instance, When you hold down the "a" key (just as an example, of course it could be any key) and there is a second delay before the cursor will then register "aaaaaaa".  The same problem is happening here, so when a direction key is pressed the frame animations begin  before the physical movement starts. Which results in an animation that looks like the character is running in place and then finally starts moving after about a 1 or 2 seconds.

Any thoughts, ideas, or advice on a fix would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance, all.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;


character.stop();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPress);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyRelease);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterThisFrame);

var moving:int = 4;
var animate:Boolean = false;


function onKeyPress(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {       
       switch(e.keyCode)
         {
            case 37:  moving = 1; character.gotoAndStop(6); character.x-=5; break; //left
            case 38:  moving = 2; character.gotoAndStop(4); character.y-=5; break; //up 
            case 39:  moving = 3; character.gotoAndStop(8); character.x+=5; break; //right
            case 40:  moving = 4; character.gotoAndStop(2); character.y+=5; break; //down
            case 32: handleAttack();                

        }

        animate = false;

    }

 function onKeyRelease(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
        switch(moving)
        {
            case 1: character.gotoAndStop(6); break; //left
            case 2: character.gotoAndStop(4); break; //up
            case 3: character.gotoAndStop(8); break; //right
            case 4: character.gotoAndStop(2); break; //down
        }

        animate = true;
    }   


    function handleAttack():void
    {           
        switch (moving)
        {
            case 1:  character.gotoAndStop(11); break;   //left
            case 2:  character.gotoAndStop(10); break;   //up 
            case 3:  character.gotoAndStop(12); break;   //right
            case 4:  character.gotoAndStop(9); break;    //down
        }
    }



   function onEnterThisFrame(e:Event):void
       {

         if (animate == true)
        {
            switch (moving) 
            {
                case 1: if(character.currentFrame == 6) character.gotoAndStop(5); break;
                case 2: if(character.currentFrame == 4) character.gotoAndStop(3); break;
                case 3: if(character.currentFrame == 8) character.gotoAndStop(7); break;
                case 4: if(character.currentFrame == 2) character.gotoAndStop(1); break;
            }
        }


   }
```

Comment: Why not use enter frame as a main loop for your game? In your code, in `enter frame` you only manage movement state...

Answer (score 0):

Have bools for each direction and change your onKeyPress and onKeyRelease to set these, then check them and move your character in your onEnterThisFrame function.