# Flash As3 key press issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok so my main problem here is that the `KeyboardEvent` for flash is wayyy to slow. Lets say i press the left arrow. For some reason, the movement delays and then moves. When I was doing double jumping or jumping at all, I had to hold the button rather than do a single press. My question is is there a way for flash to detect  a single press of any key and how do I solve the movement delay for keyCode?

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

//Initialized variables

var theKey:KeyObject = new KeyObject(stage);//Help the stage checks for keypressed objects
var hspeed:Number = 0;// horizontal speed
var vspeed:Number = 0;// vertical speed
var gravity:Number = 2;//Gravity
var friction:Number  = .5;//Friction
var ground:int = 800;//Bottom of the stage
var JumpMax:Number = 0;//Double jump

//All Booleans (Mainly player states)
var aDown:Boolean = false;//Press left key
var dDown:Boolean = false;//Press right key
var Jumped:Boolean = false;//Player in jumping state
var AttackMode:Boolean = false;//Player in attacking state
var CrouchMode:Boolean = false;//Player in crouched state
var RightSide:Boolean = false;//Player hitting right side of block
var LeftSide:Boolean = false;//Player hitting left side of block
var DownSide:Boolean = false;//Player hitting the top of block
var UpSide:Boolean = false;//Player hits bottom of block

ultraDaimyo.gotoAndStop("idleDaimyo");

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyYeet);
function keyYeet(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        dDown = true;

    }
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        aDown = true;

    }
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.C)
  {
    AttackMode = true;

  }
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.W || Jumped == true)
  {
    Jumped = true;
  }
 }

 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyNot);
 function keyNot(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
 {
    dDown = false; 
 }
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
 {
    aDown = false; 
 }
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.C)
 {
    AttackMode = false; 
 }
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
 {
    Jumped = false; 
 }
 }


 stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameCycle);
 function gameCycle(e:Event):void
{
hspeed *= friction;
ultraDaimyo.x += hspeed;
ultraDaimyo.y += gravity;

if(AttackMode)
      {
        ultraDaimyo.gotoAndStop("attackDaimyo");
        ultraDaimyo.x += 5;
        if(ultraDaimyo.scaleX == -1)
          {
            ultraDaimyo.gotoAndStop("attackDaimyo");
            ultraDaimyo.x -= 10;
          }
      }
if(Jumped == true)
  {
     ultraDaimyo.y -= 30;
     ultraDaimyo.gotoAndStop("jumpDaimyo");
  } 
if(dDown)
  {
     hspeed += 20;
     ultraDaimyo.gotoAndStop("runDaimyo");
     ultraDaimyo.scaleX = 1;
  }
if(aDown)
  {
     hspeed -= 20;
     ultraDaimyo.gotoAndStop("runDaimyo");
     ultraDaimyo.scaleX = -1;
  }
if(!aDown && !dDown && !AttackMode && !Jumped)
  {
    ultraDaimyo.gotoAndStop("idleDaimyo");
  }


if(ultraDaimyo.x - ultraDaimyo.width/2 < 0)//If the player goes past the left side
  {
    ultraDaimyo.x = ultraDaimyo.width/2;
  }
if(ultraDaimyo.x + ultraDaimyo.width/2 > 1400)//If the player goes past right
  {
    ultraDaimyo.x = 1400 - ultraDaimyo.width/2;//Player cant go past
  } 
if(ultraDaimyo.y + ultraDaimyo.height/2 < floor && Jumped)//If we are above the floor
  {
    if(Jumped)
      {
          ultraDaimyo.gotoAndStop("jumpDaimyo");
      }
    gravity++;//Accelerate gravity in the process
  }
if(ultraDaimyo.y + ultraDaimyo.height/2 > floor)
  {
    Jumped = false;//If we are on the floor then we're not jumping
    gravity = 0;//Gravity can no longer be applied
    ultraDaimyo.y = floor - ultraDaimyo.height/2;//Player sits on top of the floor
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer is yes.  If you want a better answer than that, please edit your question and show you current code so someone can point out where you're delay is coming from.

Comment: Update: I just added the entire code for my character Daimyo here. Now the problem is Keyboard event itself. The keyCode just delays for a brief moment then does the movement. Also, Im still wondering if as3 can detect a press only rather than a hold. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "press only"?  Essentially the `KEY_UP` event would the equivalent of a press.        Your code looks ok, if I had to guess, your delay is from your `gotoAndStop` and not the event itself.  Try putting a trace statement in your key down handler (`keyYeet`) and see if that trace fires immediately vs. whatever your seeing on your timeline.

Comment: Yes it can detect short taps & long press. Why do you need stuff like `if(aDown)` statements & booleans in your `function keyYeet`? That `ultraDaimyo...` code will fire continously as long as there's an "in use" signal being sent by that relevant key. Experiment & see...

Comment: I meant by being able to detect a simple tap rather than actually holding it down. Im having problem with the jumping because I actually have to hold down the up key to actually have the player in the jumping state until it reaches the ground. I just want flash to simply detect one brief tap and then execute the entire jump process after.

Comment: You should show your jump code since that's the main problem. When you talk of a "jumping state" is this issue about showing a specific animation frame(s)? Maybe you have a boolean causing it to reset when you release the up key? If that the case, you should set a `Jumped = true` boolean (when you single press up key) that puts your MC in the "jumping state" and it does not change state until it reaches the ground, when thats detected, only then does it reset to idle state or whatever you do. Again you need to show that particular jump handling code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

`KeyboardEvent` does not fire continuously, because that would make it hard to detect single keystrokes.

What you have to do is use the `KeyboardEvent` to only change the speed variable, but apply the speed to the position variable in a different continuous `Event`, namely `Event.ENTER_FRAME`.

I created an example based on your code:

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

//Initialized variables
var speedX:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyYeet);

function keyYeet(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        speedX = 20;
    }

    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        speedX = -20;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyNot);

function keyNot(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.D || e.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        speedX = 0;
    }
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameCycle);

function gameCycle(e:Event):void
{
    ultraDaimyo.x += speedX;
}
```

The idea is to set the speed when the key goes down to a certain value and to set it back to 0 when the key goes back up.

The speed is continuously applied to the position.

---

from the comments:

> Please double check your first sentence.

Sure enough there was a typo, but the content is as I intended it to be.

> the result is continous firing = continuous movement.

Not for me. Chances are this is different for different (keyboard) hardware or software (operating system, flash runtime). Other people have similar experiences as can be seen in these duplicates of the question at hand.

- [key_down delay action script 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23578768/4347580)
- [Actionscript 3-- Trying to fix a delay that is occuring upon key press.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22242702/4347580)

Let's not look at display objects moving around and comparing opinions about whether they move continuously or not. Let's collect some comparable data instead.

Here's a little document class that counts the delay between 5 occurrences of the `KEY_DOWN` event.

To use it, make sure the application has focus and press down any button until the trace appears in the output panel.

Releasing the key resets the array and another key can be held down.

```
package 
{
    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var oldTime:Number = 0;
        private var deltaTimes:Array = [];

        public function Main() 
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
        }

        private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            var currentTime:Number = getTimer();

            // collect 5 time differences between two consecutive occurrences of this event

            if (deltaTimes.length < 5)
            {
                deltaTimes.push(currentTime - oldTime)    
            }
            else
            {
                stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
                trace(deltaTimes);
            }

            oldTime = currentTime;           
        }

        private function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent = null):void
        {
            deltaTimes = [];

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my results:

```
7584,499,49,51,50
2117,500,50,50,50
1786,500,50,50,49
1375,499,48,50,52
1395,500,50,50,50
1385,500,50,50,50
1243,501,47,52,49
2167,501,49,50,50
1587,500,50,50,50
3871,500,50,48,53
2237,500,49,51,49
1715,500,47,53,50
```

Three important things can be observed:

1. The first value is obviously not interesting as it is the time
   between two button presses. (I just wanted to put this together
   quickly)
2. The second value is roughly 500ms, which means between the first and
   second occurrence of the event, half a second of time passed.
3. The last 3 values are roughly 50ms, which is much shorter than
   500ms. This is the rate at which the event will keep firing as long as the key is pressed

The code I provided in my answer above fixes this problem.

Comment: Please double check your first sentence. Try **[this code](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3keyboard/2.php)** (make `my_mc` from a small coloured rectangle). You will see that as long the left or right keys are giving an **"in use"** signal, the result is continous firing = continuous movement. Same code detects single taps or long press of key... No need for a key up to stop the movement (though in Asker's code that would affect the `ultraDaimyo.scaleX = ...` code, so perhaps they do need a "key up" signal to stop constant scaling).

Comment: Hi, I took a look. It's good stuff. Regarding your opening sentence though I disagree. I say **it does fire continously** otherwise it's hard to detect a **long press**. To detect a single stroke, the user simply fires the event once via a single press on k/board. It also has the capabilty to fire continously too. I mean as far as human perception is concerned. This answers Asker's concern about single tap vs long press. I confirmed it can do both. I think their problem is having a really long delay (imagine waiting a 2 or 3 second delay after you press jump to get a code reaction).

Comment: I haven't checked those links yet but it's strange cos I get an almost instant reaction (to my eyes) from keyboard. You confirmed it settles at **50ms**. That's **1/20th** of a second. Don't you think this ability to fire 20 times per second can count as "continous"? So why tell me it doesn't but then show me evidence that it can? Just read the Asker's question one more time (especially the delay in jumping issue) and you'll understand why I told them what I did. Otherwise I did learn something new (I did not know about 50ms, so it gave me idea to fix a "thing" in one of my apps). +1 given

Comment: @VC.One: I showed evidence of the discontinuity as asked for by the question: "*For some reason, the movement delays and then moves.*"